# How to get rid of these small black bugs on gardenia

Tags: pest-control, pests, container-gardening, pest-damage, pesticide

My gardenia is more than 6 months old. it was in good health.

Suddenly I noticed that the gardenia leaves are turning yellow. I thought that it was because of natural causes. So, I ignored it initially.

Then I saw that even small leaves are turning yellow.

Then I check for the bugs and I saw these:

[image]

I sprayed insecticide and later also sprayed (strong force) it with water thought that I am safe now. But, unfortunately, they are keeping coming back in a couple of days. So, clearly, I could not kill the pest properly.

Any suggestion? My gardenia looks very tired :( . How can I revive it ?